# Get posts on page by others on FB API v2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm really struggling with Facebook's new v2 API.

I want to write a **cron job** to fetch messages posted to my facebook **page wall by others**. This will be for competition entries, they post a message/link on the company wall and the cron job picks this up as an entry.

The documentation is all over the place, do I have to get an app token via manage_pages scope and hard code this into my app? What happens every x days when this expires, do I really have to manually generate it again and update my cron jobs every x days!? If so how is this sustainable?

I'm using

`$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/207072886058771/feed' );`

But this only works if I manually click a "login" button every time I load this cron in my browser.

Comment: It’s rather _you_ who is “all over the place” … for example you seem to confuse app- with page access tokens, and it doesn’t look as if you’d done _proper_ research into token expiry either.

Comment: Believe me I've spent ages pouring through their docs. The trouble is the API is so new there's very little help to be had around the web unless your specific scenario is in their docs, which mine isn't

Comment: Graph API v2.0 is new – but I have not seen anything yet about fetching wall posts from a page being handled differently now than it was in V1.0.

Comment: I've managed to do it without the graph API see below

Answer (score 0):

OK I was able to do a CURL request to:

https://graph.facebook.com/207072886058771/feed?access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET

This returns a list of all posts on the page, then a simple check to make sure from->id != PAGE_ID will give you posts by others.

Comment: If you want _only_ posts by others, it would be better to use FQL and an appropriate stream_filter in the first place …

Comment: And btw., the method you’re using now is API version _1_ …

Comment: Not according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: Thanks, hadn’t seen yet that they want to discontinue FQL – but only _after_ v2, so that is still a long time to come. And what does the docs page about access tokens now have to do with what API version you are using? And you are __definitively__ not using v2 with the call you have shown – because if that was the case, then the path would have to be prefixed with `/v2.0/`

Comment: What I meant was it wasn't deprecated, adding /v2.0/ still works, so it's definitely part of the v2 API.

Comment: Well who said otherwise? Page tokens work basically the same, and that the feed of a page can be accessed using that way, in v2 the same as in v1 before, is clearly stated in the docs …